# addClass does not work properly

Tags: jquery, callback

I have a small but annoying and weird problem. I have 2 buttons that add a class to a p element. When a user clicks on a button it adds the class "groen" or "rood" (depends on the button) to the p element. The user can then click on that p element with the class "groen" or "rood" and it should then do something but it does not do anything. But if I give the p element the class "groen" or "rood" in the HTML it does do the jQuery actions.

I have jsFiddle of my project here: http://jsfiddle.net/c3dfj/

If you want to see the problem click on a "ja" or "nee" checkbox and check the p element with the "akkoord" text in it. It shows you "akkoord groen" or "akkoord rood". (depends on the button you clicked). But if you click on the "akoord" it does not do anything. I you add the class rood/groen into the HTML it does work :/

```
<p class="akkoord"><br/>Akkoord</p>
```

Comment: The project is getting quite large (i'm like on 90% done) so posting all the code here wouldn't work. I added a jsFiddle to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind the click handler there's no `p` element with either '.rood' or '.groen' use `on` instead

```
    $('body').on('click','.rood',function() {
        var container = $(this).parents('.container_vragen').find('.container2');
            container.fadeOut(400, function() {
               container
                   .css('overflow', 'hidden')
                   .appendTo("#niet_geregeld");
               $(this).parents('#niet_geregeld')
                   .find('.container2')
                   .css('padding-left', '30px')
                   .fadeIn(400);
            });
    });

    $('body').on('click','.groen',function() {
        var container = $(this).parents('.container_vragen').find('.container2');
            container.fadeOut(400, function() {
               container.css('overflow', 'hidden')
                        .appendTo("#geregeld");
               $(this).parents('#geregeld')
                      .find('.container2') 
                      .css('padding-left', '30px')
                      .fadeIn(400);
            });
    });
```

this way any element that has the class '.rood' or '.groen' respectively at the time the button is pressed will react to the click. You can of course refine the 'body' selector to an enclosing div or similar which would be recommended if possible but in your code you are selecting all '.rood' and all '.groon' elements so simply to stay compatible with that I've used 'body'. I've also taken the liberty to simplify the code a bit to eliminate unnecessary selections

Comment: Thanks, it's annoying that small mistakes creep up when you're busy for a while. Good explanation and help!

Answer (score 0):

Try with jQuery .hasClass(), if it does have class than redirect to your method or call the function. else apply the function addClass().

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<div class="parent">
  <button class="addgroen">addgroen</button>
  <button class="addrood">addrood</button>
  <p>
  </p>
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$('.addgroen').click(function(){
   $('p').removeClass('rood').addClass('groen');
})
$('.addrood').click(function(){
   $('p').removeClass('groen').addClass('rood');
})
```

on jQuery <  1.7 you should use :

```
$('.groen').live('click',function(){
   alert('p element with groen class clicked');
});
$('.rood').live('click',function(){
   alert('p element with rood class clicked');
});
```

on jquery >1.6 you should use :

```
$('.parent').on('click','.groen',function(){
   alert('p element with groen class clicked');
});
$('.parent').on('click','.rood',function(){
   alert('p element with rood class clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically adding someting you should go for jQuery ON and OFF

[Jquery ON](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[Jquery OFF](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$(document).on('click','.rood',function() {
//YOUR CODE
});
```